# Windows 10 Error

Tags: error

I've used Tor browser on many different generations of Windows with no problem. But when I download the bundle the install works perfect but than when I try to open it I get a Tor browser profile problem. It says:

> Tor Browser does not have permission to access the profile. Please
>   adjust your file system permissions and try again

I've tried deleting and reinstalling, and running as admin and none of these options worked. There is only one profile on this computer so I can not figure out what to do for the life of me.

Answer (score 2):

Never run it as admin, nothing in Tor Browser requires administrator privileges. Running it as administrator greatly increases the damage that could be done if your browser was compromised.

The problem is where you are extracting Tor Browser to. Directories like `C:\`, `C:\Program Files\` or `C:\Program Files (x86)` all have administrator requirements to edit (for very good security reasons).

Instead, install it to some folder associated with your user account, a common example would be `C:\Users\user\Desktop\` (where your username is `user`), this will ensure that Tor Browser will have sufficient file and folder permissions to the place it is extracted without any need for special permissions.

Comment: why should that be though? There are plenty of other programs that install in program files that have no need for admin privileges, why does Tor need to be installed in a user account directory?